# Is it OK to create a single channel per client?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, signalr, channel

I have a case, where the data is streamed from an ASP.NET Core server to a JS client continuously during a long period of time (let's say about 20 hours) with quite a high frequency, let's say, tens of messages per second.

In microsoft's [manuals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/streaming?view=aspnetcore-7.0) on SignalR it is advised to return `IAsyncEnumerable<T>` or `ChannelReader<T>` in case when in is required to stream data piecewise from server to client.

The question is, if I would like to use a Channels approach, how much overhead does it introduce? I've reviewed the source code of `System.Threading.Channels` and SignalR, but it is still unclear for me, how much performant is this. Another question is if it is any better than utilizing a plain old `Clients.All.SendAsync(byte[])`? From one point of view, it looks like it introduces less complexity against the Channels. How common is it to create a channel per client and how it is better in managing clients/connections?

Comment: Creating a channel for each client is a common approach when you need to manage each client connection and its data flow independently. It allows you fine-grained control over the streaming process for each client.

Comment: For the overhead you care about, your specific scenario must be tested and analyzed to assess the actual performance impact and ensure it meets your application requirements.

Comment: @JasonPan, you're absolutely right and an assessment is needed indeed. The question is more of ones' experience in similar cases.